# Other Names for Sierpinski Reals / Leaning Tower of L'viv

Tags: set-theory, terminology

There is a poset constructed by combining in a certain way the usual order on the reals with any well-order on the reals (I can provide details if needed). I've heard it called the "Sierpinski Reals" and "The Leaning Tower of L'viv", but I do not see anything online when I search these names. Is this construction known by any other names?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These slides on [Suslin lattice](https://web.archive.org/web/20120124122721/http://www.math.toronto.edu/raghavan/ucla.pdf) mention a *Sierpinski poset*, as does [Theory of Relations](https://books.google.com/books?id=R-jlxKxJma0C&pg=PA72&lpg=PA72&dq=%22poset%22%2bsierpinski&source=bl&ots=e98uvYVFl8&sig=EYTLzCeXeqRpksGKy-FBeRmbV8Q&hl=en&sa=X&ei=KdMYT92HH9PXiAKa8eXKCA&ved=0CCwQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q&f=false) by Roland Fraïssé.

Edit: Also the term Sierpinski tower such as mentioned in [Random Walks on a Fractal Solid](https://doi.org/10.1023/A:1026474407979).

Comment: The "Sierpinski poset" defined [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=R-jlxKxJma0C&lpg=PA72&ots=e98uvYVFl8&dq=%22poset%22%2Bsierpinski&pg=PA47#v=onepage&q&f=false) in Theory of Relations is indeed the one I was thinking of. Thank you.